# NetBeans: How to disable project files copying on remote host

Tags: c++, netbeans, remote-debugging, netbeans-8.1

I'm trying to build project on remote host using NetBeans 8.1. 
I create the project and try to build it. NetBeans shows me in build log

```
Copying project files to /home/user/.netbeans/remote/hostname/desktop-Linux-x86_64 at user@hostname
Building project files list...
Checking directory structure...
Checking previously uploaded files...
Checking links...
Uploading changed files:
    Zipping 1 changed files...
    Uploading zip to user@hostname...
    Unzipping changed files...
Checking exec permissions...
Uploading changed files finished successfully.
```

NetBeans builds my project in this directory not in the project home directory.

How can I disable files copying and make NetBeans to build project in it original directory?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you had selected SFTP, you have to select "System Level file sharing (NFS, Samba)
then do Path Mapper, that's all

[image]